# Solr Search not showing results

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr, doing a prototype.
I indexed 5 documents and committed. Now, if I go to http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/ , I see that 5 documents are indexed. If I search for any of the terms in the documents, I don't see any results. But, if I do *:*, I do see all the 5 records.

What am I doing wrong. Any ideas? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probable Problems:

1. Solr has a cache of the query.  Hold shift when hitting the refresh button.
2. The field you are querying on is not indexed.  Change the configuration of your schema file.
3. You may need to specify a field to query.  Use the "field:query" syntax.

Comment: Hi Jon, I put the indexed=true in all the fields.

Comment: <field name="fw-title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" /> Note: I took the existing schema.xml file that came in the solr/conf folder and added the new fields as per the need. I only updated the schema.xml, but not the solrconfig.xml file. Do I need to update that too? Sorry, I am new.

Comment: :) http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=fw-title:thai is showing the results. Thanks. But, http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=thai is not showing results. What do I need to do if I want to search on the entire index. Thanks.

Comment: You can either modify the defaultSearchField in your schema file, or if you want to query multiple fields at once use a dismax query. (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin)

Comment: I set <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField> and then used copyfield <copyField source="fw-title" dest="text"/>. Also I put other fields also as copyField. But the search is not showing results. Any Ideas? Also, one more question sir - If I am setting the field as indexed=true, why do I need to again say defaultsearchfield, dismax etc. Thank you.

Comment: You have to tell Solr which field you want to search.  If you are copying the fw-title field to the text field, you will need to tell it to search the text field.  I would recommend not using the copy fields, and just use the dismax query because if you copy fields, you will not be able to highlight the results.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for the tip. Even though, I am adding fw-title to copyField and setting the defaultsearchfield, I am unable to search that field. Any clues? Note: I do see the dismax setup in solrconfig.xml file for the default fields came with solr examples. Is that's why my copyfield is not working? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'd have to see your schema.xml file to tell